# Service receive null Intent without START_STICKY flag

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have a Service that manages different types of Intents.

Depending on the Intent it's managing it returns START_REDELIVER_INTENT or START_NOT_STICKY.

It never returns START_STICKY.
So I put an assert (intent != null) at the begin of onStartCommand.

Anyway, from Firebase crashreports I see that it happened few times and on different Android version.

I do NOT send null intents to the Service in all my code and I've never seen it happen in all my tests.

Does anyone know when it should happen?
I've not found any evidence in Service documentation.

Thanks

Comment: is your service gets killed ?

Comment: @jiteshmohite, I guess... but I don't really know. I only see the stack with the assert fails. I'm not yet comfortable with Firebase, I don't find a way to relate the crash with previous events tracked in Firebase.